# Access JavaScript objects within an Array using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an array filled with objects in JavaScript. I passed the entire array to an API. How can I access an object's properties, using C#?

Comment: Do you mean JSON, or full JavaScript, which can have content that can't be parsed as JSON?

Comment: Where do you want to do this action? Is this in a MVC view or ASP.NET web form? Or did you mean in the API? Or something completely different?

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define C# model class that matches JavaScript objects, accept array of this object in your controller and you will have the objects to use within controller. JavaScript objects have to be sent in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

## A. JSON in C# generally

Here are popular choices for interacting with json in .NET:

- (.NET Core) System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer. Plase see [How to serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)
- JSON.NET with models. Please see [Serializing and Deserializing JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)
- JSON.NET's Linq to JSON. Please see [LINQtoJSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) or [Querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

## B ASP.NET example

Check out `Examine the PostTodoItem create method` in [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-posttodoitem-create-method).

I shows you how to consume a json payloads.

#### Json

```
{
  "name":"walk dog",
  "isComplete":true
}
```

#### Model

```
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Controller action

```
// POST: api/TodoItems
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)
{
    _context.TodoItems.Add(todoItem);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    //return CreatedAtAction("GetTodoItem", new { id = todoItem.Id }, todoItem);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = todoItem.Id }, todoItem);
}
```